# Submitting two form using javascript but failed

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

i have been trying to Submit two form using javascript and failed.  i have searched stackoverflow but none of the javascript works ...

also tried this [Submit two forms with one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button)

here is my code ... my full page is very long so i have just pasted the two form code here ...
And each field of form1 (regForm) is required .. and form2 (frmAdd) contains a while 
loop... both of them forms are different i guess... so any solution with javascript or any alternative with these forms ...

```
  <script>
  submitForms = function(){
    document.forms["regForm"].submit();
    document.forms["frmAdd"].submit();
}
  </script>

      <form action="userdata.php" method="post" name="regForm" id="regForm" >

      <h2><em>Personal Details : </em></h2></br>

        <table width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" class="forms">
            <tr>
                <td width="22%">NAME<span class="required"><font color="#CC0000">*</font></span></td> 
                <td width="78%"> 
              <input name="full_name" type="text" id="full_name" size="40" value="<? echo $row_settings['full_name']; ?>" class="required"></td>
            </tr>
          <tr> 
               <td>FATHER'S NAME<span class="required"><font color="#CC0000">*</font></span></td> 
               <td> 
              <input name="f_name" type="text" id="f_name" size="40" value="<? echo $row_settings['f_name']; ?>" class="required"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>MOTHER'S NAME<span class="required"><font color="#CC0000">*</font></span></td> 
                <td> 
              <input name="m_name" type="text" id="m_name" size="40" value="<? echo $row_settings['m_name']; ?>" class="required"></td>
            </tr>
          <tr> 
               <td>NATIONALITY<span class="required"><font color="#CC0000">*</font></span></td> 
               <td> 
              <input name="nationality" type="text" id="nationality" size="40" value="<? echo $row_settings['nationality']; ?>" class="required"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>RELIGION<span class="required"><font color="#CC0000">*</font></span></td> 
                <td> 
              <input name="religion" type="text" id="religion" size="40" value="<? echo $row_settings['religion']; ?>" class="required"></td>
          </tr>
        </table></br>

        <p align="center">
            <!-- previous button   <input name="doSave" type="submit" id="doSave" value="Submit">  -->
        </p>
    </form> 

        <form action="userdata.php" name="frmAdd" method="post">

<table width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" class="forms">
  <tr>
    <td width="5"> <div align="center">NO</div></td>
    <td width="91"> <div align="center">Employer's NAME</div></td>
    <td width="160"> <div align="center">COUNTRY</div></td>
    <td width="198"> <div align="center">POSITION</div></td>
    <td width="70"> <div align="center">FROM</div></td>
    <td width="70"> <div align="center">TO</div></td>
    <td width="70"> <div align="center">SALARY</div></td>
    <td width="70"> <div align="center">REASONS FOR LEAVING</div></td>
  </tr>

  <?php for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++) { ?>

  <tr>
    <th width="5"> <div align="center"><? echo $i . "."; ?></div></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="emp_name<?=$i;?>" size="25"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="emp_country<?=$i;?>" size="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="emp_pos<?=$i;?>" size="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="emp_frm<?=$i;?>" size="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="emp_to<?=$i;?>" size="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="emp_sal<?=$i;?>" size="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="emp_lev<?=$i;?>" size="25"></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  </table>
  </br>
    <!-- previous button <input type="submit" name="doHis" value="Save"> -->
  <input type="hidden" name="hdlfrm" value="<?=$i;?>">

  <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="submitForms()" />
```

Comment: your both <form are not valid they have no ending </form> tag.

Comment: well i said i have just copy pasted from my large page ... but fixed now ... do u have any solution now @moskito-x

Comment: :Have you seen my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not submit two different forms on one page. You have a race condition.

If you want to submit two forms at once, either combine them and handle it at the server OR you can use Ajax to submit them.

Comment: then what should i do ? @epascarello

Comment: rethink what you are doing.

Comment: why this method doesnt work ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button

Comment: or document.getElementById('otherForm').submit(); these method suppose to work on one page right ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is install jQuery and use the `find` method then `serialize` the whole thing and send it using a jQuery `post`, `get`, or `ajax` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are missing "tags" and the code is not correct in some places.
It would be much easier if you just shortened the code to relevant parts and then posted.
So I had to do that for you.

You should test the following code. As long as that does not work, there is no need even more "form input" to write.

the test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    submitForms = function(){
    document.forms["regForm"].submit();
    window.setTimeout(submitB,1000)
    } 

    function submitB() {
    document.forms["frmAdd"].submit();
    }
    </script>
    <title>Emergency Table - Update</title>
</head>

<body>
 <form action="writea.php" method="post" name="regForm" id="regForm" >
    <h2><em>Personal Details : </em></h2></br>
    <table width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" class="forms">
        <tr>
            <td width="22%">NAME<span class="required"><font color="#CC0000">*</font></span></td> 
            <td width="78%"> 
             <input name="full_name" type="text" id="full_name" size="40" value="Romeo Delta" class="required"></td>
        </tr>
    </table></br>
 </form> 

 <form action="writeb.php" name="frmAdd" method="post">
  <table width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" class="forms">
  <tr>
    <td width="5"> <div align="center">TEST</div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </br>
  <input type="hidden" name="hdlfrm" value="1000">
  <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="submitForms()" />
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

writea.php

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['full_name'])) { $hdl = $_POST['full_name']; } else { $hdl = "Err."; }
  $fp = fopen('dataa.txt', 'a+');
  fwrite($fp, "Hello from write A : ".$hdl."\r\n");
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

writeb.php

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['hdlfrm'])) { $hdl = $_POST['hdlfrm']; } else { $hdl = "Err."; }
  $fp = fopen('datab.txt', 'a+');
  fwrite($fp, "Hello from write B : ".$hdl."\r\n");
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

After submit the content of dataa.txt and datab.txt should be.

dataa.txt
`Hello from write A : Romeo Delta`
datab.txt
`Hello from write B : 1000`

Answer (score 0):

If you do normal form post in your page the first submit action will done and redirects to that page and second form post will not done my solution is better to use ajax post method and submit these two forms hope this helpful..

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution for this ... used this jquery and jquery form js ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() { 

        $('#form1').ajaxForm(function() { 
        });
        $('#form2').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Your Submitted Information has been Saved !");
                window.location = "userdata.php";    
                return true;

        });
        $("#submitEverything").click(function(){
        mySubmitFunction();
        return false;
});

}); 

function mySubmitFunction() {
        $("#form2").submit();
        $("#form1").submit();
}

</script>
```

> userdata.php is the page where this code was pasted
>   and have to use two different action in forms (like form1 action="page1" and form2 action="page2")