# Jquery Modal window form - submitting two forms with one submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, forms

I am trying to create a modal window form that submits two forms upon submission.  One is a hidden form and the other is the modal window form being viewed.  It only seems to be submitting one of the forms (reschedule_meeting_form) and just skips the other one entirely without an error.  Any advice you can give is most appreciated.

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {   //creates a modal to post the new message being composed to the server 
$('#emailposting_form').dialog({   
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 375,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [
        {
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }},
    {
        text: "Submit",
        click: function() {
            $('#emailform').submit();     //this one is not working
            $('#reschedule_meeting_form').submit();    //this one is working
        }}
    ]
});
$('#reschedule_meeting_button').button().click(function(e){
    $('#emailposting_form').dialog('open');
});
```

});

**Modal Form HTML:**

```
    <!-- modal form --> 
<div id="emailposting_form" title="Send Message">
   <form id="emailform" method="POST" action="/sendemailmessage" name="emailposting">
        <input type="text" style="display: none;" value="{{meeting_request.key()}}" id="reschedule_meeting_message" name="reschedule_meeting_message">
      <p>
        <label for="recipient">To:</label>
        <input type="text" name="recipient" id="recipient" value="{{meeting_request.requesting_user}}"  readonly>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
        <input type="text"  name="subject" id="subject" value="Suggest New Meeting Time">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="content">Message: </label>
        <textarea  name="content" id ="content"  class="textarea" rows="4" style=""></textarea>
      </p>
    </form>
</div>

<input type="button" id="reschedule_meeting_button" name="reschedule_meeting_button" value="Suggest New Meeting Time" >
```

**Hidden Form HTML:**

```
    <form id="reschedule_meeting_form" method="POST" action="/meetingresponse" name="reschedule_meeting_form" style="display:none;">   
        <input type="text" style="display: none;" value="{{meeting_request.key()}}" name="reschedule_meeting">
    </form>
```

Comment: You'll probably have to target one of the forms (the first one you submit) at a hidden `<iframe>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit two forms with one button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button)