# submit 2 forms with chained dropdowns and single submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm working in a Financial System, and currently I'm developing a query panel to compare items   during different years.

My question is how can I create 2 forms that contains chained values and submit the data using a single submit button?

This is how it looks like:

http://oi60.tinypic.com/2e31gk4.jpg

I was trying to use the answer from this post ([Submit two forms with one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button)) but doesnt work for me.

And here is the code so far:

```
<body>
<form name="doublecombo">
<p><select name="category" size="1" onChange="redirect(this.options.selectedIndex)">
<option>Group_1</option>
<option>Group_2</option>
<option>Group_3</option>
</select>
<select name="type_item" size="1">
<option value="value1">Subitem 1 Group_1</option>
<option value="value2">Subitem 2 Group_1</option>
<option value="value3">Subitem 3 Group_1</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Data"
onClick="go()">
</p>

  <script>
var groups=document.doublecombo.category.options.length
var group=new Array(groups)
for (i=0; i<groups; i++)
group[i]=new Array()

group[0][0]=new Option("Subitem 1 Group_1","value1")
group[0][1]=new Option("Subitem 2 Group_1","value2")
group[0][2]=new Option("Subitem 3 Group_1","value3")

group[1][0]=new Option("Subitem 1 Group_2","value1")
group[1][1]=new Option("Subitem 2 Group_2","value2")

group[2][0]=new Option("Subitem 1 Group_3","value1")
group[2][1]=new Option("Subitem 2 Group_3","value2")
group[2][2]=new Option("Subitem 3 Group_3","value3")
group[2][3]=new Option("Subitem 4 Group_3","value4")

var temp=document.doublecombo.type_item

function redirect(x){
for (m=temp.options.length-1;m>0;m--)
temp.options[m]=null
for (i=0;i<group[x].length;i++){
temp.options[i]=new Option(group[x][i].text,group[x][i].value)
}
temp.options[0].selected=true
}

function go(){
location=temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value
}
//-->
  </script>


</form><!-- -->
```

Any help will be really appreciated, I'm stuck on this feature.

Comment: why not using single form?

Answer (score 0):

In your go method, you should change action attr of your form and submit it.

```
function go(event){
  var combo = document.doublecombo.type_item;
  document.doublecombo.action = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;
  //u can manually submit, but you should prevent default action
  document.doublecombo.submit();
  event.preventDefault();
  //or just leave it, because clicking to submit input will automatically submit the form
}
```

and for input

```
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Data" onClick="go(event);">
```