# Submit multiple forms one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have two separate forms with radio buttons. I need to make a button, clicking which submit two forms.

```
<form action="/second_vote" method="post" id="poll-view-voting" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="choices">
        <div class="form-item form-type-radios form-item-choice">
            <div id="edit-choice" class="form-radios">
                <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-choice">
                    <input type="radio" id="edit-choice-1" name="choice" value="1" class="form-radio">
                    <label class="option" for="edit-choice-1">1 </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="edit-vote" name="op" value="Vote" class="form-submit">
</form>

<form action="/second_vote" method="post" id="poll-view-voting--2" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="choices">
        <div class="form-item form-type-radios form-item-choice">
            <div id="edit-choice--2" class="form-radios">
                <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-choice">
                    <input type="radio" id="edit-choice-3" name="choice" value="3" class="form-radio">
                    <label class="option" for="edit-choice-3">1 </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="edit-vote--2" name="op" value="Vote" class="form-submit">
</form>
```

I try to do like this, but only sent the first form.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function submitDetailsForm() {
        $('#poll-view-voting').submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can't submit two forms in one page request. Either use AJAX or merge the forms to make one.

Comment: Why not use single form and indexed inputs? `<input name="choice[]"/>`? Because you can't submit two forms, unless using Ajax.

Comment: Using ajax is a better way

Comment: I sense a conceptual misunderstanding in the question. Can you give a valid use case (reason) why you need to submit two forms simultaneously and can't handle it server-side in a single submission?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't send two form in one single request. You should use some AJAX request to send both of them in sequence, or, even better, use just one form (you're using the same `action` for both of your form..)

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the first form using AJAX, otherwise the submission of one will prevent the other from being submitted.

Answer (score -2):

1

```
<form action="/second_vote" method="post" id="poll-view-voting--2" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="choices">
        <div class="form-item form-type-radios form-item-choice">
            <div id="edit-choice--2" class="form-radios">
                <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-choice">
                    <input type="radio" id="edit-choice-3" name="choice" value="3" class="form-radio">
                    <label class="option" for="edit-choice-3">1 </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="submitDetailsForm()" />


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function submitDetailsForm() {
            $('#poll-view-voting').submit();
            $('#poll-view-voting--2').submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: This will not submit **both** forms.

Comment: More importantly, have *you*? Only 1 form will be submitted.

Comment: Look this ;) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button I have not tried, but seems to be submitted both forms

Comment: That case could have any manner of code listening for a submission and preventing it when it happens. In the case above, as is, you will only submit one form (make one page request) this way.

Comment: The comments in the accepted answer of the other question say the same thing: it might work, or it might not. It might (and will) fail in some browsers and situations.

Comment: Best thing is play it safe and assume `submit()` is non-reentrant.