# How to post mutliple forms from a webpage

Tags: javascript

I want to post 2  forms using javscript, but I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone help me?

It seems like I need to submit the first form Async according to this but I don't follow their code: [Submit two forms with one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button)

HTML

```
<form name="form1" action="https://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" target = "me1">
<input type="hidden" name="oid" value="00Df00000000001" />
</form>


<form name="form2" action="https://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST"  >
<input type="hidden" name="oid" value="00Df00000000001" />
</form>

<input name="submit" value="Submit Form" onclick="submitForms ()" type="button">
```

JS

```
function submitForms(){
    document.forms["form1"].submit(); /* should be Async?*/
    document.forms["form2"].submit();
}
```

Comment: You should read the second answer on that page. And also the comment under the code you've copied which says **This is plain wrong**

Comment: You have to use ajax to submit a form.

Comment: any particular reason why you need 2 forms for this? Both forms are submitted to the same `action`

Comment: thanks @user3087839 do you have some sample code?

Comment: @Savv I need to create 2 records in by DB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit two forms with one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button)

Answer (score 0):

```
var str1 = $( "form1" ).serialize();
var str2 = $( "form2" ).serialize();
ajaxReq(url,str1);
ajaxReq(url,str2);
    function ajaxReq(url,data){
      var request = $.ajax({
              url: url,
              type: "POST",
              data: data,
              dataType: "html"
            });

            request.done(function(html) {
                console.log('SUCCESS')
            });

            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                console.log("AJAX REQUEST FAILED" + textStatus);
            });
    }
```

Comment: I declared the url in my form component, I have to do it again in the ajax?

Comment: You have to use ajax. If you submit form then browser will refresh page and second form can not be submitted

Comment: ok... sorry, I never used ajax before.. I put your code in my JS function, and i'm getting syntax error. it doesn't recognize the $

Comment: @nivyaj It's jQuery. Also I hope you are running this script on the `test.salesforce.com` domain (or it has enabled CORS for you) otherwise this won't work either

Comment: can i do it in javascript?

Comment: yes you do it in javascript. Maybe you need a tutorial for ajax.
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/