# get input of all forms in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get input of every form in my page that their name is `name` my forms are like this

```
<form class="form" role="form" onsubmit="completeSave(this)">
      <div class="form-body">
           <div class="form-group">
               <label>name</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                                               value="{{$media->name}}">
            </div>
       </div>
 </form>
// next form!
 <form class="form" role="form" onsubmit="completeSave(this)">
      <div class="form-body">
           <div class="form-group">
               <label>name</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                                               value="{{$media->name}}">
            </div>
       </div>
 </form>
```

I already have some code that do something with each form (an ajax request ) but I want to have a button in a page that submit all forms data

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="completeSaveAll()">submit</button>
```

i tried this javascript code :

```
 function completeSaveAll() {
        var form = $('form');
        form.each(function () {
            console.log(this.find("[name=name]"));
        })
  }
```

but it doesn't work how can I do it?

Comment: try console.log($(this).find("[name=name]"));

Comment: if I understood correct, this question related for this topic [Submit two forms with one button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button)

Comment: `.find()` is a jQuery method and can only be chained to a jQuery object, i.e.`$(this)` and not `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `serializeArray()`

```
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : 'url',
data : $('#form').serializeArray()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button) previously answered similar question

I would say your `onclick` handler might not be able to initialize successfully as you are using jQuery `$` in the handlerFunction `completeSaveAll` and DOM elements might render before `jQuery` is fetched.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<form class="form" role="form">
      <div class="form-body">
           <div class="form-group">
               <label>name</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="name1">
            </div>
       </div>
 </form>
// next form!
 <form class="form" role="form">
      <div class="form-body">
           <div class="form-group">
               <label>name</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="name2">
            </div>
       </div>
 </form>
 <button class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
```

**jQuery:**

Use `submit` and prevent the **default** process, so that only the values will be returned.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  form.each((key, val)=>
    console.log(val.name.value))
})
```

And then trigger this above using your `button` outside of these forms

```
$('button').click(()=> 
    $('form').trigger('submit')
)
```

Replace the values with `{{$media->name}}` or whatever you want to do.

[**Demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/Dezain/qw4ks9gj/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple:

```
'use strict';
var name = $('input[name="name"]');
$.each(name , function(i,el){
  console.log(i);
});
```

Here you go jsbin for it

https://jsbin.com/pewulimefu/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```js
function completeSaveAll() {
  debugger
        //var form = $('form');
        $('form').each(function () {
            console.log($(this).find("[name=name]").val());
        })
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" role="form" onsubmit="completeSave(this)">
      <div class="form-body">
           <div class="form-group">
               <label>name</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                                               value="{{$media->name}}">
            </div>
       </div>
 </form>
// next form!
 <form class="form" role="form" onsubmit="completeSave(this)">
      <div class="form-body">
           <div class="form-group">
               <label>name</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                                               value="{{$media->name}}">
            </div>
       </div>
 </form>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="completeSaveAll()">submit</button>
```

Comment: Down voter, please comment so that I can update if there is any mistake.