# Submit data of current form along with other form as well

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, laravel

I have two forms

1. `first_form` is for ajax request to load new input data which is displayed in `second_form` as input fields(this is already done)
2. `second_form` is to submit all data of its own and `first_form` as well(this is not achieved)

`first_form` is using `form-inline` to display inputs horizontally while the other form is a normal form so i cannot combine both the forms.

So when user clicks submit button of the `second_form` i want to send all its data along with the data of the `first_form` as well.

Example:

```
<form id="first_form" class="form-inline">
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Load</button> // This loads fields for second form

</form>

<form id="second_form">
<div class="loaded_data"> // this div is loaded with ajax
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button> // This must send all fields of first and second form
</div>
</form>
```

I do not want to use ajax for second form. The form will be submitted and store method of Laravel controller will be called for further processing

Comment: Why not just use an AJAX call?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @Raj here is the link please try with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button

Comment: @JayBlanchard Im using laravel which will call the store method when second form is submitted. so i want it to be a normal form submmission not ajax

Comment: do you not believe in giving the form elements a name attribute?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you have access to the [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method. You can grab all the data from form 1 and add it to the data of form 2 in a `$.ajax` call.

```
var form1Data = $('#first_form').serialize();
```

You can then send form1Data along with your second form:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'server/form.php',
    data: {
        form1: form1Data,
        form2: $('#second_form').serialize();
    }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    console.log('all done:', msg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get values from second_form to first_form when second form is submit:

```
$('#second_form').submit(function({
   $('#in_1_1').val($('#in_2_1').val());
   $('#in_1_2').val($('#in_2_2').val());
});
```

In HMTL add ids to inputs:

```
<form id="first_form" class="form-inline">
<input type="text"  id="in_1_1"/>
<input type="text"  id="in_1_2"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Load</button> // This loads fields for second form
</form>

<form id="second_form">
  <div class="loaded_data"> // this div is loaded with ajax
  <input type="text" id="in_2_1" />
  <input type="text" id="in_2_2" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button> // This must send all fields of first and second form
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.