# How to save to two models in one django form?

Tags: python, django

I currently have a working form for job tickets using django 2.0. I want to add the ability for multiple file uploads as supporting docs and assets. I can easily add this into the admin side of things using inlines, but how would I accomplish something similar on the front end of the site? I'm not sure how to have a form submit to two models when a key/id has yet to be set. I'm using primary keys to associate the files with the entries...

models.py:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
class File(models.model)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m')
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, models.set_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

admin.py

```
class FileInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = File
   extra = 0

@admin.register(Job)
class JobAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['ticket_number']
    inlines = [FileInline]
```

This system is great in my admin and in my templates, but I just can't figure out how to get these two to live in one form together. Is there a better way to be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use two forms and link the same button to submit both of them. See this link here[SO Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button), by containing them in both in a div and ensuring the required fields are set, you should only have to add this functionality.

Comment: You can then have your forms post to each view you need. Im sure there are other ways to tackle this.