# One of my form's data doesn't seem to be setting properly when attempting to submit via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post

I'm working on a website that will submit 2 forms, a hidden one that will send the data to a database and the visible one that will mail the form contents to a user. I looked up how to send multiple forms via javascript, and when I sent it the form that sent data to the database would work but the form that sent the data in an email wouldn't, the email would just be empty. I have hMailServer setup for local testing currently.

```
**index.php forms
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="sendData.php">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-controls left-sec">
                            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" required>
                            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required>
                            <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-controls right-sec">
                            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Type Message" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-controls">
                            <input id="submitButton" type="button" name="submit1" class="btn" value="Send Message">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
<form id="form2" name="form2" style="display:none;" type="hidden" method="POST" action="sendData.php">
                        <input style="display:none;" type="hidden" id="dbname" name="dbname">
                        <input style="display:none;" type="hidden" id="dbemail" name="dbemail">
                        <input style="display:none;" type="hidden" id="dbsubject" name="dbsubject">
                        <input style="display:none;" type="hidden" id="dbmessage" name="dbmessage">
</form>
```

```
<script>
    "use strict";
    var btn = document.getElementById("submitButton");
    btn.onclick = submitForms; // calls function in forms.js, forms.js is included in index.php
</script>
```

```
// forms.js
"use strict";
function submitForms(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var dbname = document.getElementById("dbname");
    var dbemail = document.getElementById("dbemail");
    var dbsubject = document.getElementById("dbsubject");
    var dbmessage = document.getElementById("dbmessage");
    debugger;
    dbname.value = name;
    dbemail.value = email;
    dbsubject.value = subject;
    dbmessage.value = message;
    var f1 = document.getElementById("form1");
    var f2 = document.getElementById("form2");
    f1.submit();
    f2.submit();

}
```

```
// forms.js debugging, lines cut out for convenience, f1 and f1 elements dont seem to be registering correctly as inputs
"use strict";
function submitForms(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value; name = "testname"
    var dbname = document.getElementById("dbname"); dbname = input#dbname {accept: "", alt: "", autocomplete: "", autofocus: false, defaultChecked: false, …}
    var f1 = document.getElementById("form1"); f1 = form#form1
    var f2 = document.getElementById("form2"); f2 = form#form2 {0: input#dbname, 1: input#dbemail, 2: input#dbsubject, 3: input#dbmessage, acceptCharset: "", action: "http://localhost/test/sendData.php", autocomplete: "on", enctype: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", encoding: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", …}

    f1.submit();
    f2.submit();

}
```

```
// sendData.php
<?php
session_start();
include("../Include/storeData.php");
include("../Include/sendMail.php");
if(isset($_POST["name"])){ // if I use just isset($_POST), database info sends but mail is empty, I put in $_POST["name"] to test my theory that it wasn't setting correctly
    echo "<h1 style='font-weight: bolder; color: green; text-align: center;'>Message has been sent. Thank you!</h1>";
    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'index.php';\",1500);</script>";
    $_SESSION = [];
}
?>
```

```
// storeData.php
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
if(!$link){
    die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error());
}

function checkExists($l){
    $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($l, "luberlaw");
    if(!$db_selected){
        $sql = "CREATE DATABASE db";
        if(mysqli_query($l, $sql)){
            mysqli_select_db($l, "db");
            $query = "CREATE TABLE msgData (ID int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      sName varchar(255) NOT NULL, sEmail varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
                      sSubject varchar(255) NOT NULL, sMessage varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
                      dateEntered TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                      PRIMARY KEY (ID))";
            $result = mysqli_query($l, $query);
        }else{
            echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error() . ".\n";
        }
    }
}

function storeData($l){
    $name = $_POST["dbname"];
    $email = $_POST["dbemail"];
    $subject = $_POST["dbsubject"];
    $message = $_POST["dbmessage"];
    $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($l, "luberlaw");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO msgData (sName, sEmail, sSubject, sMessage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($l, $sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $email, $subject, $message);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    mysqli_close($l);
}

if(isset($_POST["name"])){
    checkExists($link);
    storeData($link);
}
```

```
//sendmail.php
<?php

function sendMail(){
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $subject = "website message: " . $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $to = "websiteownersemail";
    $body = "<html>
                <head>
                <title>website Message</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                <table>
                <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>$name</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <p>$message</p>
                </body>
                </html>";
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    $headers[] = "Bcc: myemail"; //testing purposes
    mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));
}

if(isset($_POST["name"]))
    sendMail();
?>
```

I expect both forms to submit, but clearly something isn't working correctly with form1. I originally just had isset($_POST) in my php files which would allow the database to be filled but the email sent to be empty. I put isset($_POST["name"]) as a test to see if form1 data was setting, which it wasn't.

***Edit included sendmail and storedata php files***

Comment: why did you add two forms? Keep hidden fields in same form?

Comment: Are you trying to handle 2 separate POST requests in one go in PHP? That will not work. You need to merge the forms in JS or handle them separately in PHP.

Comment: one more thing why you add style attribute to hidden input fields? only adding hidden will work.

Comment: I handle them separately in php. The storeData.php handles the form2 data and the sendMail.php handles form1 data

Comment: I'd go for one form and one page that will process the data. First data insertion in the database and only if it is ok it will send the message to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are handling it in wrong way. You have submit button in `form1` that will pass the `form1` data only to PHP file, how are you expecting that it will send `form2` as well?

Please move all hidden fields to form1 and remove style attributes from all hidden fields.

Comment: I'm pretty new to php and js and was just going based off of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button

Comment: You should add html forms properly?

Comment: Just move hidden fields to form1, let me know if you still have any issue.

Comment: that worked. thank you. sorry i've only had a couple months of php and js experience