# I want to submit two form data by clicking on create button how can i do so

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, antd

[image: 1]

I am trying to Recieve both form data in single click which is create button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using `reactjs` and know `useRef`. You can use `useRef` to reference those two submit buttons from different forms. First you need to create a variable

```
const buttonRef = useRef()
```

Now you have to add `ref={buttonRef}` to both of those button tags as an attribute. Lastly, you have to add a function that triggers those button clicks. You can add `onClick` attribute to Create button. You can add this to Create button `onClick={() => buttonRef.currentRef.click()}`.

These steps will let you submit two form. But won't merge two form data into one.