submit 2 form data in single submit using jquery ajax
I want to submit 2 form data in single submit button.
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form id="form2">
  <input type="email" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

What I use for single form:
  $.ajax({
    url: '/submit_form_data.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#form1").serialize();,

    success: function(response) {
      // Handle the response from the server.
    }
  });

How can I pass both form data in single ajax submit?

$('#form1, #form2').serialize() ...?

@CBroe its not submiting any thing

https://jsfiddle.net/3rcde46z/ clearly shows, that this creates the parameter string to be expected here. If anything within your app is not working with that, then we'd need more details.

Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button

you can concat two formdata, like this:


  $.ajax({
    url: '/submit_form_data.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#form1").serialize() + '&' + $("#form2").serialize() ,

    success: function(response) {
      // Handle the response from the server.
    }
  });




i got working solution as :
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Create a FormData object for each form.
  var formData1 = new FormData($('#form1')[0]);
  var formData2 = new FormData($('#form2')[0]);

  // Append the FormData objects to a single object.
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('formData1', formData1);
  formData.append('formData2', formData2);

  // Make an Ajax request to the server, passing in the FormData object as the data parameter.
  $.ajax({
    url: '/submit_form_data.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false, // Don't process the data as a query string.
    contentType: false, // Don't set the Content-Type header.
    success: function(response) {
      // Handle the response from the server.
    }
  });
});

